# Repopulating Postgres database with seed data for testing

Tags: postgresql, testing, database-restore

I am trying to create some integration tests for my app,
and part of this I want to seed my application every time
the tests run. The database needs to remain connected however,
so `dropdb` / `createdb` is not an option.

I am currently doing:

`pg_dump -F custom -O -x -d test-db > ./tests/test-db`

Before the test, and:

`pg_restore --clean -d test-db ./tests/test-db`

To restore the DB after every test runs.

This doesn't seem to work however as the `pg_restore` command throws lots of errors:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 3771; 2618 175960 RULE skilled_outcome_group _RETURN dan
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  cannot drop rule _RETURN on view public.skilled_outcome_group because view public.skilled_outcome_group requires it
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 184; 1259 174070 TABLE outcome_group_skill dan
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  cannot drop table public.outcome_group_skill because other objects depend on it
```

And it carries on like this... I thought `--clean` was meant to completely drop everything,
however `pg_restore` is complaining that it cannot drop tables / views ? Is there something wrong with my combination of flags in `pg_dump` / `pg_restore` ?

Answer (score 0):

`pg_restore` can be used to generate the export script, in which case some flags such as `--clean` can be used. The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) says

> This script output is equivalent to the plain text output format of
>   pg_dump. Some of the options controlling the output are therefore
>   analogous to pg_dump options.

When you run `pg_restore` to restore the DB, it can only apply the commands that exists in the script.

You would need to run `pg_dump` with the `--clean` option, so that this command is applied when restoring the DB.